# How to pre-process brightness and contrast to find accurate differences between images in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, image-comparison

I am making a program that compares and points out the differences between the two images using the `skimage` library.

```py
def get_structural_simlarity(first_image, second_image):
    print("[Console] Calculating differences")
    # Pre-process Image
    first_gray = convert_to_gray(first_image)
    second_gray = convert_to_gray(second_image)
    # Compare
    (score, diff_img) = structural_similarity(first_gray, second_gray, full=True)
    # Convert return format to cv2 readable
    diff_img = convert_to_cv2_format(diff_img)
    print("[Console] Similarity score of {:.4f}%".format(score * 100))
    return diff_img
```

It works how I wanted it to when comparing two different images. However, the problem is when I compare `Image 1` with `Image 2`, where `Image 2` is `Image 1` with contrast and brightness adjusted. What I intended to do is for the program to point out there are no differences. However, the contrast and brightness difference changed the result.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Contour_1_2]

So far, I have tried using the `skimage.exposure.equalize_adapthist` method to adjust the contrast for all input images.

`equalize_adapthist(image, kernel_size=None, clip_limit=0.01, nbins=256)`

[image: Image 1 Adjusted]

[image: Image 2 Adjusted]

However, the result is still showing differences in the images.

[image: Filled_1_2_adjusted]

[image: Contour_1_3_adjusted]

I need help finding a way to readjust and match the brightness and contrast, or even color between the input images to point out more accurate differences.

Comment: Normalize the images by subtracting their mean and then dividing that by their standard deviation

Comment: Or use that equation to change one image to match the other. See https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/